# Best Programming Practice for using packages(Java)

Tags: java

Which one is better to do...
importing package or using them directly inside a method

for eg:-

```
import java.util.Arrays;
int arr[] = new int[10];
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

Is the above one better?
-----(OR)-------

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
java.util.Arrays.sort(arr);
```

According to me both perform same thing...
But I wanted to know which of these is the best programming practice...

Comment: Since the very purpose of imports is to avoid the second case, I would say the very existence of imports points to the first option.

Comment: I don't personally like the inlined package, i'd rather use the `import` statement. Inlining packages looks overwhelming

Comment: there is no real difference, the only time you need to use full path in the code, is if you are using two classes with the same name but different package signature in the same class

Comment: It is a matter of taste, and therefor an opinion and thus off-topic. The generated bytecode is the same, so it is purely about readability, clarity and disambiguation.

Comment: The only correct response to this is: "I don't care about programming practices, I am **not** going to type out the full package dozens of times.*. Import statements are a tool you have available to you, they're there for a reason. **use them**. If ever you see inlined packages, it is probably code produced by a tool and not by a person.

Answer (score 1):

Right now there is no difference but you'll start seeing it when you have your own `Arrays` class.

If it is unique class name go with first way. That's the best way to organise your imports. If you have duplicated class names (although not suggestable), you'll be forced to have the second way.

Answer (score 0):

It's all by developer but I prefer import classes because code it's more readable.

Second is old best practice but as I say it is from the developer to the developer